# How to exclude (.not) selector with Jquery (with live function)

Tags: jquery, click, live

I have an live event on all link or multiple selector on the page and i have multiple selector i don't want active the event. Normally, when the first live function is executed on all link, the e.preventDefault() is activate. But if one of the selector is in my exclude list, i want execute the link normally. I have tried this code :

```
$(selectorListA).live('click',function(e) {
    // stop all event
});

$(selectorListB).live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do action
});
```

I have tried this to :

```
$(selectorListA).not(selectorListB).live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do action
});
```

All of this solutions don't work, the only way i have is this code, it work but in chrome an error is showed before the click event is execute, hmmm i'm not sure is good :

```
$(selectorListB).live('click',function(e) {
    die();
});

$(selectorListA).live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do action
});
```

I don't know what i can take for execute all selectorListA with exclude all selectorListB. Can you help me please, thank you!

Comment: `die()` I think the only reason that may work is because `die` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error you get in Chrome?  Seems that the problem is not with your selectors.

Either way, something like this should work:

```
$(selectorListA).live('click',function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(selectorListB)) }{
        // stuff for b group only
    }

    // stuff for both groups
});
```

The version using `.not()` won't work because `live` attaches a document-level handler and uses the original selector to test whether the event should apply.  So actually selecting and filtering before calling live won't work as it would with `click()`.